# CSS : focus on an element to display another previously hidden element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make this work on pure CSS, I know how to do it in Jquery, but I really want(if possible) to do this in CSS.

I have spans with classes going from "mens1" to 9.

And I have divs going from "mention1" to 9.
All divs should not be visible at first.

When I click the matching span, I want the focus to show the corresponding div
(i.e clicking on mens1 should display mention1) and hide all the others.

I have tried the following without success :

```
.mention1{
display: none;
}

.mens1:focus ~ .mention1{
display: block;
}

.mens1:focus ~ .mention2, .mention3, .mention4, .mention5, .mention6, .mention7, .mention8, .mention9 {
display:none;
}
```

HTML :

```
<table class="column">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="inner">
                                <table class="contents">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="path/to/website" target="_blank">
    <img src="path/to/image1.jpg" ></a>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text">
                                                <div class="boltex">Title of 1
    </div><br/>text of 1
    <div class="year">year of 1<div class="prices">pricing of 1</div><br/><span class="mens1">mentions</span></div>     </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>



 <div class="mention1 secondclass"> mention of 1</div>
```

I also tried just letting one class in there, no changes

Comment: This bit should be repeated `.mens1:focus ~ ` before every `.mention[n]`.

Comment: thanks, that is good to know, but shouldn't the display:block at least work then ?

Comment: We'd need to see your HTML to comment on that.

Comment: updated answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look this solution)

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
  display: none;
}

.checkbox:checked + .div {
  display: block;
}

.span:focus + div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
<label class="label">
  <div class="span"></div>
  <input type="radio" name="1" class="checkbox" />
  <div class="div"></div>
 </label>
</li>
<li>
<label class="label">
  <div class="span"></div>
  <input type="radio" name="1" class="checkbox" />
  <div class="div"></div>
 </label>
</li>
<li>
<label class="label">
  <div class="span"></div>
  <input type="radio" name="1" class="checkbox" />
  <div class="div"></div>
 </label>
</li>
<li>
<label class="label">
  <div class="span"></div>
  <input type="radio" name="1" class="checkbox" />
  <div class="div"></div>
 </label>
</li>
<li>
<label class="label">
  <div class="span"></div>
  <input type="radio" name="1" class="checkbox" />
  <div class="div"></div>
 </label>
</li>
<li>
<label class="label">
  <div class="span"></div>
  <input type="radio" name="1" class="checkbox" />
  <div class="div"></div>
 </label>
</li>
</ul>
```

```
li {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
  display: none;
}

.checkbox:checked + .div {
  display: block;
}

.span:focus + div {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: thank you, it makes a lot more sense now, I can't believe I expected my thing to work with my div outside of the element that needs to be clicked...haha

Answer (score 2):

Here's something easier. You can target the beginning or a portion of a class name, instead of infinitely applying permutations.

```
.mens1:focus ~ div[class^='mention']{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reach the .mentions element without placing them inside a single .mens element using pseudo classes.
Please display your HTML to clarify.

Comment: thanks for that useful info, though I haven't been able to fix it following what you said (so I probably didn't apply it well), I updated my answer with html