# Make element appear on focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following element which I want to appear on focus. When navigating the webpage by pressing Tab on the keyboard.

I have .pagemenu that is hidden by default and appears when I hover on .stub. I want .pagemenu to appear when I reach .stub navigating the page via Tab button on the keyboard (accessibility).

Usually, `:focus` does exactly what I need. Usually, when I use `:focus` for an element, and property like `background color`, background color changes, but setting `:focus` for .stub or .pagenav is not working.

Ok, I understand now that it's impossible to focus on elements that are not displayed, so I can't focus on .pagenav. But I can focus on .sub, cant I? Then why is this not working:

```
.stub a:focus .pagenav {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: -3px;
width: calc(100% + 6px);
}
```

I don't want to use checkbox as the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984282/css-focus-on-an-element-to-display-another-previously-hidden-element) suggests because I don't want to add extra lines in HTML (and I have trouble understanding checkbox).

Adding opacity to .pagenav would be a good idea, but it messes with the width of .stub when .pagenav isn't displayed (no idea why) and it removes centering of .pagenav content. I'm open to any solutions including JS.

[gengns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5796090/gengns) below has proposed a solution with opacity that eliminates issues described above but still doesn't solve the problem with `:focus` on Tab.

What do I need to do to make .pagenav appear on focus on either .stub or .pagenav itself?

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("stub").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("stub").style.top = "150px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

```css
.stub {
  background-color: #577284;
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #ff8000;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

#stublink {
  color: #F3E0BE;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.stub:hover .pagenav {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
}

.pagenav {
  background-color: #577284;
  display: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 3px solid #ff8000;
  border-top: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.pagenav a {
  display: block;
  color: #F3E0BE;
  padding: 6px 0px 0px 8px;
}

.pagenav a:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 5px 0 0 0 #ff8000
}

body {
  height: 200vh
}

;
@media only screen and (max-width: 670px) {
  .stub {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: auto;
  }
  .stub:hover .pagenav {
   display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: -3px;
width: calc(100% + 6px);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="stub" id="stub">
    <div class="pagenav">
      <a href="#last">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>02.19 03.20</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#previous">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>02.18 02.19</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#dec17">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>12.17 04.18</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#nov17">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>11.17 01.18</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#sep16">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>09.16 11.17</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#sep15">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>09.15 08.16</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#jan15">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>01.15 03.16</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#jan14">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>01.14 08.15</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
    </div><a id="stublink" href=#>Pagemenu</a>
  </div>
  <script></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and put #stublink BEFORE your navigation and add following CSS, as the TAB key will not focus .stub but the #stublink-element:

```
.stub:hover .pagenav,
    #stublink:focus + .pagenav{
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: -3px;
      width: calc(100% + 6px);
    }
```

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("stub").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("stub").style.top = "150px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

```css
.stub {
  background-color: #577284;
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #ff8000;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

#stublink {
  color: #F3E0BE;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.stub:hover .pagenav,
.stub:focus-within .pagenav,
#stublink:focus + .pagenav{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
}

.pagenav {
  background-color: #577284;
  display: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 3px solid #ff8000;
  border-top: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.pagenav a {
  display: block;
  color: #F3E0BE;
  padding: 6px 0px 0px 8px;
}

.pagenav a:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 5px 0 0 0 #ff8000
}

body {
  height: 200vh
}

;
@media only screen and (max-width: 670px) {
  .stub {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: auto;
  }
  .stub:hover .pagenav {
   display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: -3px;
width: calc(100% + 6px);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="stub" id="stub">
    <a id="stublink" href=#>Pagemenu</a>
    <div class="pagenav">
      <a href="#last">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>02.19 03.20</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#previous">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>02.18 02.19</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#dec17">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>12.17 04.18</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#nov17">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>11.17 01.18</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#sep16">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>09.16 11.17</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#sep15">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>09.15 08.16</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#jan15">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>01.15 03.16</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      <a href="#jan14">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>01.14 08.15</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td class="two"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Great solution. But why is it disappearing right after pressing Tab second time? Is it possible not just show .pagenav, but navigate its' links?

Comment: Fot that you will have to use :focus-within on the #stub element

Comment: It works! I admire your skill, thank you. I can award bounty only in 4 hours. I will do it as soon as it becomes available.

Comment: I'd appreciate that ;)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you well, you wanna show your `.pagenav` each time an user is over your `.stub` or the hidden `.pagenav` itself. You can do it easily with the opacity as you said and changing the heights : )

**Updated**: Display menu when Tab is pressed.

```js
const $pagenav = document.querySelector('.pagenav')

document.onkeydown = e =>
  e.code == 'Tab' && $pagenav.classList.toggle('show')
```

```css
.stub {
  background-color: #577284;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #ff8000;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#stublink {
  color: #F3E0BE;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.stub .pagenav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  left: -3px;
  background-color: #577284;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  filter: opacity(0);

}

.stub:hover .pagenav, .pagenav.show {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  filter: opacity(100);
  height: auto;
  border: 3px solid #ff8000;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-top: none;
}

.pagenav a {
  display: block;
  color: #F3E0BE;
  padding: 6px 0px 0px 8px;
}

.pagenav a:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 5px 0 0 0 #ff8000
}
```

```html
<div class="stub">
  <div class="pagenav">
    <a href="#last">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>02.19 03.20</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td class="two"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </a>
    <a href="#previous">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>02.18 02.19</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td class="two"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </a>
    <a href="#dec17">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>12.17 04.18</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td class="two"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </a>
    <a href="#nov17">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>11.17 01.18</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td class="two"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </a>
    <a href="#sep16">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>09.16 11.17</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td class="two"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </a>
    <a href="#sep15">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>09.15 08.16</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td class="two"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </a>
    <a href="#jan15">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>01.15 03.16</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td class="two"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </a>
    <a href="#jan14">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>01.14 08.15</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td class="two"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </a>
  </div><a id="stublink" href=#>Pagemenu</a>
</div>
```

Hope this help or at least point you to the right direction ^^

Comment: It works better than when I tried to do it, but still, the height of .stub gets messed up. You can see how it changes on hover. And :focus is not working either.

Comment: You can adjust the heights as you want to ; ) but what is the other focus effect you are trying to achieve, maybe I can help you with that.

Comment: When I try to adjust the height .stub only shortens from the bottom even with left, top and bottom set to auto. Focus is when I press "tab" on the keyboard. The .pagenav doesn't appear in this case just like when using display instead of opacity.

Comment: I have updated my post. Run the code snippet above, click the result area (to get context) and then press Tab. It should work, however I would recommend you to use another key or combination because Tab is widely use to move between elements. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for willing to help. I want to use Tab because it's widely used to move between elements. That's exactly why I want to use :focus - because I want to enable users to navigate the .pagemenu using navigation between elements. :focus usually works for that purpose, but not on this element.

Answer (score 0):

You cant focus elements which are not displayed yet (display: none).
Maybe you handle this by a small helper element which is displayed?

Comment: I have .stub which is always displayed (well, I also have javascript which hides it when scrolling down and makes it appear when scrolling up, but it doesn't affect the question).